# Ubuntu on Asus K53tk laptop overheating

Tags: overheating

I installed latest Ubuntu distribution , and my laptop is overheating. The fan is always at like 60 % power , decreases 1 min then again it start to 60 %. It is not a laptop issue , isnt dirty with dust inside , ive just cleaned out, and in windows the temperatures are as expected , 40 idle , 80 full throttle. And as far as i know , an Ubuntu working laptop should be less heated then a windows one , if both are fresh installs. I think it is something from the APU with 7670m video card. Laptop spec - AMD A6 3420m, 4 GB ram , 6520g+7670m video card. Hope you can understand my issue even my english isnt too good. Good luck everyone , and great job !

Answer (score 1):

dude this is normal due to reason that when you install ubuntu on AMD apu it's by default use `opensource x.org driver`. So it uses maximum pontential of cpu. Your cpu is capable of boosting it's frequency to 2.4GHz and base clock is 1.5GHz.
due to these drivers cpu run always at 2.4GHz. To avoid this issue you have to install AMD proprietary driver using additional drivers menu in ubuntu and you can use `indicator-cpufreq` to control cpufrequency
To install it just type in terminal

> sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq

and after that using it you can use `ondemand cpu governer`. That will solve you issue. and second thing you say that your cpu cooling fan run for while and then stops for 1 minute, perhaps this is due to your BIOS settings. In BIOS there is setting called `fan always on` you set it off. so it stops for a while and then starts again.
To monitor cpu temperature you can use `Psensor.` You can install it using ubuntu software center.